# Synonyms for "participant"

Tags: synonyms

Is there a synonym for *participant* suitable for a research paper? I have seen words such as *colleague*, *member*, *party*, etc. in various thesauruses, but these do not fit with the meaning I am trying to convey. I am looking at using *participant* as “someone who participated in an experiment”.

Comment: Probably avoid *guinea pigs*. :)

Comment: What kind of participant? Participating in conducting the experiment or participating in the experiment itself as a subject?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a medical experiment or study, proband or subject might fit. If you are talking about people who actually carried out the experiment, contributor could be a suitable word.

Answer (score 1):

If your question concerns a scientific paper, we usually have the main researcher whom we refer to as the "author" and all other researchers are called the "co-authors".  "Contributors" would be those who help you carry out your research project, with financial, logistical, structural or any other form of support.

Answer (score -1):

A suitable word would be *partaker*. Definition here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/partaker

Example: They partook in an experiment that....